# get_user_meta retrieves a serialized array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have created a new WordPress user custom field that stores the id's of the articles in a serialized array in the wp_usermeta.

```
$view= get_user_meta(get_current_user_id( ), 'views', true);
```

To retrieve it I use a foreach

```
foreach ($view['post'] as $x => $value){

 echo $x;

    }
```

However, the main problem is that I want to use the values outside the loop in a WP_Query() as array in the form array('id1', 'id2');

How can I do this?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't have to be used inside 'the loop'. You are using `get_current_user_id()` and to my knowledge this can be used anywhere in your WordPress application

Comment: the problem is that $view returns an associative array and I only need the $key's of that array returned in another array of this form array('id1', 'id2')

Comment: The `array_keys()` function returns an array containing the keys. Couldn't you use that?

Comment: It just returns more arrays and it doesn't seem to work.